# change ordering of mongo collection (handlebars/meteor)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, handlebars.js

i have a leaderboard meteor sample app consisting of names and scores:
see--> http://leaderboardtry.meteor.com/

i want the ordering of elements to toggle between the score and the name when a toggle button is clicked. Here's what I've tried:
Javascript:

```
// Set up a collection to contain player information. On the server,
// it is backed by a MongoDB collection named "players".

Players = new Meteor.Collection("players");
Session.set("sort_by", "score");  

if (Meteor.isClient) {


   Template.leaderboard.players = function () {
    return Players.find({}, {sort: {score: -1}});
  };



  Template.leaderboard.selected_name = function () {
    var player = Players.findOne(Session.get("selected_player"));
    return player && player.name;
  };

  Template.player.selected = function () {
    return Session.equals("selected_player", this._id) ? "selected" : '';
  };

  Template.leaderboard.events({
    'click input.inc': function () {
      Players.update(Session.get("selected_player"), {$inc: {score: 5}});
    },
    'click input.toggle': function(){
    var switch_sort = Session.equals("sort_by", "name")?"score":"name";
     Session.set("sort_by", switch_sort);  
     var togg = Session.get("sort_by");
     if (togg == "score"){

           Players.find({}, {sort: {score: -1}});

     } else {

                 Players.find({}, {sort: {name: -1}});


     }
  }
  });

  Template.player.events({
    'click': function () {
      Session.set("selected_player", this._id);
    }
  });
}

// On server startup, create some players if the database is empty.
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    if (Players.find().count() === 0) {
      var names = ["Ada Lovelace",
                   "Grace Hopper",
                   "Marie Curie",
                   "Carl Friedrich Gauss",
                   "Nikola Tesla",
                   "Claude Shannon"];
      for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++)
        Players.insert({name: names[i], score: Math.floor(Math.random()*10)*5});
    }
  });
}
```

HTML

```
<head>
  <title>Leaderboard</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="outer">
    {{> leaderboard}}
  </div>
</body>


<template name="leaderboard">
   <input type="button" class="toggle" value="toggle sort" />

  <div class="leaderboard">
    {{#each players}}
      {{> player}}
    {{/each}}
  </div>

  {{#if selected_name}}
  <div class="details">
    <div class="name">{{selected_name}}</div>
    <input type="button" class="inc" value="Give 5 points" />
  </div>
  {{/if}}

  {{#unless selected_name}}
  <div class="none">Click a player to select</div>
  {{/unless}}
</template>

<template name="player">
  <div class="player {{selected}}">
    <span class="name">{{name}}</span>
    <span class="score">{{score}}</span>
  </div>
</template>
```

Problem's certainly in my attempt in JS. Assistance is appreciated as I am new to meteor/mongo

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like leaderboard uses the function stored in Template.leaderboard.players to populate the list; so do you need to put the sort_by code in there? Like this?

```
Template.leaderboard.players = function () {
    var togg = Session.get("sort_by");
    if (togg == "score"){
       return Players.find({}, {sort: {score: -1}});
    } else {
        return Players.find({}, {sort: {name: -1}});
    }
};
```

This is just a suggestion - I don't know meteor, so I don't know how it knows to re-run the function.

Comment: hey actually this worked!...i think what i did previously was if(){Template.leaderboard.players = stuff} else{ Template.leaderboard.players = other stuff) as opposed to just putting the if-else inside of the function. Thanks very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to do it like this.

```
    // Set a session var to store current sort order 
    // Do this first thing in the Meteor.isClient *if*
    Meteor.startup(function(){
        Session.set("sort_by", {score: -1, name: 1});
    });
```

Notice that the players sort is taken care of here:

```
    Template.leaderboard.players = function () {
        // The commented line below is the original line in the code
        // return Players.find({}, {sort: {score: -1, name: 1}});

        // Replace line above for the line below
        return Players.find({}, {sort: Session.get("sort_by")});
    };
```

Once you have that you should handle an event from a button, so:

- Create button in the HTML file (for example):

  ```
  <input type="button" class="sort" value="Order by Name"/>
  ```
- Handle the event in JS file (notice this handler already exists, I am just adding code):

  ```
  Template.leaderboard.events({

      'click input.inc': function () {
      Players.update(Session.get("selected_player"), {$inc: {score: 5}});},

      // This is the code you need
      'click input.sort': function () {
          var sort_by = Session.get("sort_by");
          if(Object.keys(sort_by)[0] == "score"){
              Session.set("sort_by", { name: 1, score: -1 });
          }
          else{
              Session.set("sort_by", { score: -1, name: 1 });
          }
      },
  });
  ```

That should be enough.